# Application menu support for LibreOffice 3.4.1

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

I have installed LibreOffice 3.4.1.

On the website it say that it has global menu support. This doesn't work.

I have downloaded a newer version of the package `lo-menubar` which doesn't work either. I don't know if it is the newest version.

I've tried the LibreOffice v3.4.0 [workaround](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37881) but that also did not work.

Is it possible to get the Application menu working for LibreOffice 3.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension mentioned in the other posts only works for x86_64!

So if you have a 32bit Ubuntu, as I do, that won't work for you.

I found a way to make it work, tough. Certainly, it's not the most elegant way, since I have no idea how to create a Libreoffice extension from source.

You can download the modified extension for 32bit here: [lo-menubar.oxt](http://ubuntuone.com/p/13hA/)
Download it, open it, agree in Libreoffice to install it, restart Libreoffice.

I hope I didn't violate any licenses…

If you don't trust me or your just curious what I did, here is what I did:

Download the extension that was mentioned in the other answers:
 [lo-menubar.oxt](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=47502)

Get the 32bit deb from the Ubuntu repositories. Open a terminal and enter:

```
apt-get download lo-menubar
```

If you didn't change the directory, a file called *lo-menubar_0.1.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb* should be in your **home folder**.

Now open *lo-menubar.oxt* with the archive manager: Right click on the *lo-menubar.oxt*, open with archive manager (I hope it's called like that, I am using Ubuntu in German)

Now both files should be open, each in an archive manager window.

In *lo-menubar.oxt*:

1. Remove the Linux_x86_64 folder
2. Change into the folder META-INF
3. Extract *manifest.xml* (just drag it onto your desktop)
4. Right click on the **extracted** *manifest.xml* - open it with a text editor
5. Find *platform=Linux_x86_64"* and change it into *platform=Linux_x86"*
6. Find *Linux_x86_64/menubar.uno.so"* and change it into *Linux_x86/menubar.uno.so"*
7. Save the *manifest.xml* and close your text editor
8. Drag the *manifest.xml* back into the archive manager, which has *lo-menubar.oxt* opened, to overwrite that file
9. Go back to the root folder of *lo-menubar.oxt*, keep it open.

Open the lo-menubar_0.1.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb with the archive manager:  Right click on lo-menubar_0.1.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb, open with archive manager

1. Change into the folder: */usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/menubar/*
2. Drag the Linux_x86 folder into the *lo-menubar.oxt*

Close everything and open the lo-menubar.oxt. Restart Libreoffice.

Comment: Thank you this did the trick. For the 32 bit the 64 bit is below.

Comment: I've done it and uploaded the new extension to my hotmail account were you can download it at: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=c2d4f06a1337738a#cid=C2D4F06A1337738A&id=C2D4F06A1337738A%213806

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry for jumping the gun on this, as I didn't noticed I wasn't running the latest version.

This should work for libreoffice 64 bit

The debs from 
[LibreOffice.org](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) won't use Ubuntu's `libreoffice-gtk` package and installs to `/opt` breaking **[lo-menubar](https://launchpad.net/lo-menubar)** [image: Install lo-menubar] package, not the code...

However the [standalone extension](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=47502) mentioned by [DoR](https://askubuntu.com/users/114/dor) **does work** out of the box.

---

If it doesn't try to reinstall LibO 3.4.1 properly:

1. `cd` to the folder with LibO debs
2. Remove older versions:

   - `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice* lo-menubar`
3. Install Libre Office:

   - `sudo dpkg -i *.deb desktop-integration/*.deb`
4. Install the [lo-menubar extension](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=47502) (v0.1.0)
5. Close LibreOffice for the changes to take effect.

---

[image]

**Note:** 
The menubar doesn't work on Start Center and it may cause visual artifacts in its UI, its a known issue.

Comment: This breaks libre office 3.4. I've downloaded a newer version that doesn't work

Comment: Yes...me too. It has broken libreoffice 3.4.1 and i'm trying to figure it out how to solve this....

Comment: @Jorge Pinho you'll have to have the new version from here https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=47502 in the question is a link with the extension too

Comment: Thnx. But i've installed lo-menubar and since then my libreoffice 3.4.1 not appear anymore... i have purge libreoffice and have installed 3.4.1 again, but still doesn't work. How can i fix it?

Comment: remove the installed lo-menubar and install libreoffice3.4-debian-menus_3.4-103_all again it's under desktop integration. Hope that does it.

Comment: @Rens Nope... unfortunelly... only libreoffece 3.3.3 works.

Comment: I know that i've installed 3.4.1.. I know it's there, but when i try to reach the icon and i search for it, it seems that there is no icon at all. Looking to synaptic, libreoffice 3.4.1 is fully installed.

Comment: @Jorge Pinho Can't help you

Comment: @Jorge Pinho , try running it in a terminal : `libreoffice3.4` not only `libreoffice`

Comment: "command not found" it says... :(

Comment: Then you better ask a question rather than comments here. It seems that the `lo-menubar` package installed the core of the previous `3.3.x` version of LibreOffice.

Comment: @Jorge Pinho I'm sorry if my answer just complicated such a simple matter. Follow the procedure I posted, it should work.

Comment: @sergio91pt That works fine for me! Thnx!

Comment: This still doesn't work for me :-( I dodn't know why I've removed everything of libre office that I could find.

Comment: @Rens Try using purge instead of remove and make sure everything is removed including ~/.libreoffice

Answer (score -5):

Currently there's no way to integrate LibreOffice 3.4 into the Global Menu.

Comment: One google later : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-enable-global-menu-support-for-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-11-04/.  Don't know if this helps Rens, but it certainly explains why you've been voted down.